# why can't I set a setOnLongClick in this recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onlongclicklistener

**The problem: I haven't found a solution that works and allows me to use `onLongClickListener` in my recyclerview adapter**

I understand that my options seem to be either implementing an interface or using a lambda, however I've been trying everything I can find and none of them are working.

places I have tried solutions from:

[Item Onclick RecyclerView Kotlin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136732/item-onclick-recyclerview-kotlin-android)

[RecyclerView onClick in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206664/recyclerview-onclick-in-kotlin)

[How to add a click listener to my recycler view (Android kotlin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944693/how-to-add-a-click-listener-to-my-recycler-view-android-kotlin)

[RecyclerView itemClickListener in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424944/recyclerview-itemclicklistener-in-kotlin)

[Recyclerview Card Item Onclick Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314334/recyclerview-card-item-onclick-kotlin)

and everything else I could find when googling "kotlin recyclerview onClickAdapter"

I get different errors with every solution, but the main takeaway is that none of them are working, which tells me that there is probably a problem with my adapter code to begin with.

Example of one error I get: If I try to use `setOnClickListener` in the `bind` function of `TaskViewHolder`, I get the error of

> Wrong return type, expecting Boolean, received Unit

There is no passed in list because I use submitList from a viewmodel with a room database

The adapter code is based off of the [*Room with a View* code](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#11)

I have

Adapter Code:

```
class TaskRvAdapter : ListAdapter<Task, TaskRvAdapter.TaskViewHolder>(TaskComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        return TaskViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current.task)
    }

    class TaskViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val taskItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_rv_item)

        fun bind(text: String?) {
            taskItemView.text = text
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): TaskViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.task_rv_item, parent, false)
                return TaskViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class TaskComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem.task == newItem.task
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code, properly formatted

```
    fun bind(text: String?) {
        taskItemView.text = text
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("TaskRvAdapter", "item clicked: "+text)
        }
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
            Log.i("TaskRvAdapter", "item long clicked: "+text)
            return@setOnLongClickListener true
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP is looking for `onLongClickListener`, isn't it ?

Comment: I was looking for `onLongClickListener`, thanks! I was messing with this for days, thank you for the quick answer!